# Como eu debugo um método em um Web Service .asmx

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho uma chamada em minha aplicação, que vai até um WS e excuta um método e me retorna. Como eu faço para debugar o WS?

Comment: Visual Studio Remote Web Service Debugging

Comment: Onde está essa opção de Remote Web Service Debugging?

Comment: O WS é desenvolvido por você? Digo, você o tem em seu Visual Studio, ou é algo que você não tem acesso ao fonte?

Comment: Sim, foi desenvolvido por um colega aqui na empresa há 6 anos atrás. Estou chegando agora na empresa(2 semanas apenas).

Answer (score 4):

Para debugar a partir do Visual Studio você deve anexar (*attach*) ao processo de trabalho (*Work Process*) do ASP.NET. Não estou com o Visual Studio no momento mas acredito que sejam os seguintes passos:

1- Inicie a sua aplicação web que chama o WebService. Coloque o *breakpoint* em algum lugar antes do método em que o WebService é chamado.

2- No menu *Debug*, escolha *Processes*/*Attach to Proccess*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3- Uma caixa de diálogo aparece exibindo os processos. Na lista de processos disponíveis, escolha o processo aspnet_wp.exe ou w3wp.exe. Clique no botão *Attach* para anexar o WebService para o processo da aplicação.

Se você estiver com dúvida de qual processo anexar, basta rodar a aplicação/webservice que o próprio Visual Studio exibe um popup:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291236(v=vs.71).aspx) tem a parte de "*Debugging a Deployed XML Web Service*" explicando com maiores detalhes.

Comment: Vou testar conforme resposta. Esse teste não poderá ser feito hoje devido ao meu gestor ter trocado a prioridade, mas acho que isso responde meu post.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver o código fonte do WS poderá debugar pelo WCF Test Client do próprio Visual Studio, caso contrário (apenas faz uma chamada para consumir o WS) você somente poderá simular a chamada do método usando o Soap UI.