# Como colocar um break point em Web Service soap

Tags: c#, web-service

Temos um web service normal, normal digo: Não WCF. Lá tem métodos que são consumidos pela aplicação desenvolvida por nós. Como está dando um erro e pela mensagem está no WS, eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para através da minha aplicação web forms, eu entrar no WS e ver os valores das variáveis, parâmetros e etc... que esteja passando no momento.

O WS está no mesmo projeto que minha aplicação, mas estou num ambiente de prodção, mas como eu entro nesse ambiente a partir do meu computador via Visual Studio, creio que o WS que vai para o ar seja o que está no projeto e não o publicado no IIS, certo? Pois do ambiente de produção uso somente o Banco de Dados e nada mais.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41859/como-eu-debugo-um-m%C3%A9todo-em-um-web-service-asmx/41918#41918